Connecting the ESP32 to the scanned nearby devices via bluetooth
#include <BluetoothSerial.h>

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_SPP_ENABLED)
#error Serial Bluetooth not available or not enabled. It is only available for the ESP32 chip.
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

#define BT_DISCOVER_TIME 10000

static bool btScanAsync = true;
static bool btScanSync = true;

void btAdvertisedDeviceFound(BTAdvertisedDevice *pDevice) {
  Serial.printf("Found a device asynchronously: %s\n", pDevice->toString().c_str());
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test");  //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");

  if (btScanAsync) {
    Serial.print("Starting asynchronous discovery... ");
    if (SerialBT.discoverAsync(btAdvertisedDeviceFound)) {
      Serial.println("Findings will be reported in \"btAdvertisedDeviceFound\"");
      delay(10000);
      Serial.print("Stopping discoverAsync... ");
      SerialBT.discoverAsyncStop();
      Serial.println("stopped");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Error on discoverAsync f.e. not working after a \"connect\"");
    }
  }

  if (btScanSync) {
    Serial.println("Starting synchronous discovery... ");
    BTScanResults *pResults = SerialBT.discover(BT_DISCOVER_TIME);
    if (pResults) {
      pResults->dump(&Serial);
    } else {
      Serial.println("Error on BT Scan, no result!");
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
}

Output

The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!
Starting asynchronous discovery... Findings will be reported in
"btAdvertisedDeviceFound"
Found a device asynchronously: Name: Printer001, Address:
dc:0d:30:c1:7e:04, cod: 0x040680, rssi: -48
Stopping discoverAsync... stopped
Starting synchronous discovery...
Dump scan results: 1

1: Name: Printer001, Address: dc:0d:30:c1:7e:04, cod: 0x040680, rssi: -49

-- Dump finished --

Hi want to connect my esp32 to "Printer001" but this printer has a pairing code "1234". Help me please, I tried connecting it by SerialBT.connect() but it doesn't work since I don't know how to set the pairing code to the esp32

I believe you want to use setPin like in this example:
uint8_t address[6] = { 0x20, 0x13, 0x01, 0x18, 0x02, 0x26 }; // Change for your address
bool connected;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test"); 
  SerialBT.setPin("1234", 4);
  
  connected = SerialBT.connect(address);

